# Unity: Cannot add property to animation

Tags: unity-game-engine

In the Unity editor I cannot add any property to an animation. I'm trying this by double clicking the highlighted element "Scale". 
(Note: the "Add Property" button is active, not greyed out, see the image)

[image: Trying to add the property]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it is because the "Add Property" widget is hiding something on the right side. You cannot add a property by double clicking but only by clicking the plus button on the very right side (see Image).

[image: Solution]

Comment: The easier way of adding properties to an animation is actually to click on the record icon(red dot) and simply change the value of the property. It is then automatically added with a keyframe at the current frame and one at frame 0 with the original value of the property.